# How to concatenate a split word using NLP caused by tokenizers after machine translation?

Tags: nlp, tokenize, machine-translation

Russian translation produces the following result, is there a NLP function which we can use to concatenate as "Europe's" in the following string?

"Nitzchia Protector Todibo can go to one of Europe ' s top clubs"

Comment: can you share the output / result of russian translation?

Comment: Try detokenizers, e.g. https://github.com/alvations/sacremoses

Comment: Unfortunately, usually questions asking for recommendations are "off-topic" cos https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so we'll have to flag this question for closing. I did left an answer that might help you resolve your problem though.

Comment: @Jeril the above english sentence is the result of a translation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try detokenizers but because there are rules to process tokens that are expected to change `x 's` -> `x's` but not `x ' s` -> `x's`, you might have to iteratively apply the detokenizer, e.g. using `sacremoses`

```
>>> from sacremoses import MosesTokenizer, MosesDetokenizer
>>> md = MosesDetokenizer(lang='en')

>>> md.detokenize("Nitzchia Protector Todibo can go to one of Europe ' s top clubs".split())
"Nitzchia Protector Todibo can go to one of Europe 's top clubs"

>>> md.detokenize(md.detokenize("Nitzchia Protector Todibo can go to one of Europe ' s top clubs".split()).split())
"Nitzchia Protector Todibo can go to one of Europe's top clubs"
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I was the main author of the library, now it's maintained by an academic group https://github.com/hplt-project